# PHP and SQL: managing log-in via databases

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm creating a website which has a section dedicated to reviews and another one dedicated to users (log-in and sign up), both managed via databases.

In the reviews section, a user can give a review (via a form) which is uploaded in the database using this PHP code

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['pulsanteRecensione']))
    {
        $host = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "root";
        $db_nome = "ristorante";
        $tab_nome = "recensioni";

        $link = mysqli_connect($host, $username) or die ('Impossibile connettersi: '.mysqli_error());
        mysqli_select_db($link, $db_nome) or die ('Accesso non riuscito');

        $nome = $_POST['nome'];
        $recensione = $_POST['recensione'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO $tab_nome (`Nome`, `Recensione`) VALUES ('$nome', '$recensione')";
        if(mysqli_query($link, $sql))
        {
            echo "<h4 align=\"center\">Inserimento avvenuto con successo</h4>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<h4 align=\"center\">Spiacenti, inserimento non riuscito</h4>";
        }
    }
?>
```

and it works. In the same way, I want to manage the users section, so I tried this PHP code for signing up that is more or less **the same** as the previous one

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['effettuaRegistrazione']))
    {
        $nome = $_POST['nome'];
        $cognome = $_POST['cognome'];
        $mail = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $data = $_POST['dataNascita'];
        $citta = $_POST['citta'];

        $host = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "root";
        $db_nome = "ristorante";
        $tab_nome = "utenti";

        $link = mysqli_connect($host, $username) or die ('Impossibile connettersi: '.mysqli_error());
        mysqli_select_db($link, $db_nome) or die ('Accesso non riuscito');

        $sql = "INSERT INTO $tab_nome (`ID_Utente`, `Cognome`, `Nome`, `E-mail`, `Password`, `Data di nascita`, `Citta`) VALUES ('3','$cognome','$nome','$mail','$password','$data','$citta')";

        if(mysqli_query($link, $sql))
        {
            echo "<h4 align=\"center\">Inserimento avvenuto con successo</h4>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<h4 align=\"center\">Spiacenti, inserimento non riuscito</h4>";
        }
    }
?>
```

but it doesn't work, it always shows *Spiacenti, inserimento non riuscito*. What am I doing wrong?

Here there is the structure of the *utenti* table

[image]

Comment: Can you manually run the query you think you're running? Can you log the query to make sure it looks like what you think it should? Incredibly insecure code of course.

Comment: Rather than `echo "<h4 align=\"center\">Spiacenti, inserimento non riuscito</h4>";` check for the real error if any with `mysqli_error($link)` and use php's error reporting.

Comment: ID_Utente is defined as int, so get rid of the `'` in your query around the value. _AND_ password is defined as int. Sure about that??

Comment: _and_ you redefine the user's password when setting the db-password...

Comment: @Jeff about the quotes around `$password`; mysql will compensate for it. However, storing integers as passwords, really isn't recommended. I don't know why they're using that.

Comment: @mara6399 - I see you undeleted the question. I'm just wondering if what I posted did in fact solve the question. I don't want you accepting it for the wrong reason. I'm here to help and to hopefully solve the question completely. If you have any problem with it right now, I'd be more than happy to help, best I can.

Comment: @Fred-ii- as I said, it was a mistake, sorry...

Comment: By the way @mara6399 are you using a safer method to store passwords with, such as [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and increasing the password column to 255 length? You should also increase the `email` column to a much higher value, 255 is best since email addresses can be quite long. Given if you are using a register/login method on your website.

Comment: @Fred-ii- actually I'm not, it's a team work and when I told the others they said it wasn't so important, also because we don't have a lot of time. At the moment we're facing the website structure and after this I will try to convince them another time.

Concerning to the `email` column, I think there aren't 255-characters-long addresses, no-one could remember them

Comment: Ah ok @mara6399 I just don't want you guys' website/database to get hacked. We thrive on security here on Stack :-) take care (*piano piano!*) ciao.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thank you for your interest, that's kind of you ;)

Comment: You're welcome @mara6399

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For one thing, you have an AI'd column (auto_increment).

You need to replace `3` in `'3'` with `''` in VALUES.

`mysqli_error($link)` on the query would have signaled the error.

You also shouldn't be storing plain text passwords or as integers (see my note about that further down).

Use `password_hash()` and a prepared statement as you are open to an SQL injection here.

Use error reporting in case your POST arrays fail.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

However, your `$link = mysqli_connect($host, $username)` and `mysqli_select_db($link, $db_nome)` may be failing here.

Use all four arguments for it and if there is no password for the db required, use `''` only.

I.e.:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $username, '', $db_nome);
```

If your present method works, then disregard that ^

Another thing; the password column as an `int(15)`, that doesn't seem to make much sense and it is not a secure method.

Password columns are usually `varchar` and using a minimum 60 length to save a safe hash, such as [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php); the manual on [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) says that 255 is a good bet.

Also, `mysqli_error()` requires a db connection for it `mysqli_error($link)`.

You also need to make sure that the columns' lengths are long enough to hold the data. That in itself could fail silently or truncated.

---

**Note:**

Your entire code's execution is relying on this conditional statement:

`if(isset($_POST['effettuaRegistrazione'])) {...}`

If that fails, so will your entire query.

Plus, as stated in comments (by [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4830296/jeff)):

You're using the same variable for `$password` for both the POST array and the possible password for your db login; you need to change one of those.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and please, don't hate me... First of all I can't use '' to indicate an AI (MySQL returns an error) and I don't need a serious password (it's just a school project), anyway thanks for your advices about passwords, I had never heard about password_hash() before (I'm quite new at PHP). Anyway, the error must be in the query because **everything** is the same as the other code, which works.

Comment: I didn't notice I was using the same variable, I fixed this but it doesn't work anyway. I tried write the same query with values instead of variables and it works, so the problem isn't the rest of the code (which can be questionable, but as I said I'm new at PHP).

Comment: @mara6399 *lol* I won't hate you ;-) Can you use error reporting and `mysqli_error($link)` on the query to see what it does return as errors? Then let me know what those are. If you can't use `''` to replace the `'3'` with in VALUES, then try removing both the `ID_Utente` from the query and the `'3'` to see if that helps. And make sure all POST arrays have values for them.

Comment: @mara6399 just a quick note: I have to leave for a bit but will be back later. I also noticed you have 2 primary keys; one for the `ID_Utente` and for `E-mail` - you can only have one primary key. Try removing the one from `E-mail`. Error checking would have most likely thrown an error about it. I'll ping you when I get back. See if you can make it work in the meantime.

Comment: Removing `'3'` and `ID_Utente` it works but it doesn't increment, ID  becomes 1 even if there is already a record with this value. I tried again the wrong code using `mysqli_error($link)` but it doesn't give any error, just doesn't upload on the database (it doesn't matter, now it works, more or less...). Thanks a lot

Comment: I know there are two primary keys, I have read I could do this

Comment: @mara6399 I'm back. Well, you can have more than one PK; but if the goal here is to avoid duplicate email addresses, you shouldn't use a PK for the `E-mail` column but make it UNIQUE. Using more than one PK is mostly used when referencing joined tables, which doesn't seem to be the case here. I am having difficulty figuring out why it's not working as you'd like it to though; that's the bizarre thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Fred-ii-, now everything works :D. I changed my table using UNIQUE instead of a PK for email and in fact it has much sense; I had never used UNIQUE before so I wasn't sure about it. For curiosity I tried again the wrong code and now works (what?) and even the AI works removing `ID_Utente` (really, WHAT?)... maybe there was just an error with the interpretation of the code.

Comment: You're welcome @mara6399 glad to hear it. The code may have been misinterpreted, *cheers*